# Should Django enumeration types like TextChoices be compared with `is` or `==`?

Tags: python, django

The [Django Enumeration Types documention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) says that fields like `models.TextChoices`

> ... work similar to enum from Python’s standard library, but with some modifications.

It's [recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#comparisons) to compare Enumeration members by identity (with `is`):

```py
>>> Color.RED is Color.RED
True
```

But the Django docs don't seem to say anything about comparing `TextChoices` values. Which of these two options is preferred?

```py
from django.db import models


class FooChoices(models.TextChoices):
    FOO = "foo"
    BAR = "bar"


class FooModel(models.Model):
    
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=FooChoices.choices)

    @property
    def is_foo(self):
        # Either...
        return self.type == DatapointDefinitionType.FOO
        # ... or
        return self.type is DatapointDefinitionType.FOO
```

Comment: "The use of enum.unique() is enforced to ensure that values cannot be defined multiple times. This is unlikely to be expected in choices for a field." - from the django docs. I would say that they are, for all intents and purposes, an actual Enum and should be compared as such. But I can't give a definitive answer on that

Answer (score 1):

**In short**: use `==`, not `is`.

Well a `TextChoices` or `IntegerChoices` is a subclass of `Enum`, so it basically works as an `Enum` except that it has some extra logic to generate `.choices`, and also pre-processes the values to work with labels and the corresponding values.

I would however use `==`, since that means you compare with a *value*, so `FooChoices.FOO == 'foo'` will return `True`. Depending on how the choices have been generated, for example through a form, it is possible that this will work with a `str`, not a `FooChoices` object, indeed:

```
>>> type(FooChoices.choices[0][0])
<class 'str'>
```

so if you would use a `ModelForm`, or worse, post-process `request.POST`/`request.GET` into a model, `self.type` will be a *string*, not a `FooChoices` object, and therefore it would not work. So all sorts of checks you would make with reference equality to a `FooChoices` object are quite dangerous: it could fail if you compare it with the choice label.

Answer (score -2):

In python `is` operator is used to `compare identity of objects`. But the `==` operator will help you to `compare values of two objects`.So for comparing enumerated values it is best to always use `==` operator.

You can also read more about these operators here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-is-operator-in-python/

Comment: They already know this and have linked to the official documentation for Enum showing the comparison. I don't see what this answer adds other than to re-state their initial question and give a link to a less-reliable resource in GeeksforGeeks